# get data in other .cpp file

Tags: c++, sql

Im working on an online game and I have a problem with getting the ms-sql results into a other cpp file.

cpp file1 to start the query:

```
databaseManager.Query( hDB, new CQuery_AuthServer(req->awchUserId, req->awchPasswd);
```

req->awchUserId and req->awchPasswd are data from socket (username and password)

now on cpp file2 I execute the query inside a class

```
class CQuery_AuthServer : public CNtlQuery
{
public:
    CQuery_AuthServer(const WCHAR * lpszUserID, const WCHAR * lpszUserPW)
    {
        ZeroMemory( m_szUserID, MAX_SIZE_USER_ID + 1 );
        ZeroMemory( m_szUserPW, MAX_SIZE_USER_PW + 1 );

        memcpy(m_szUserID, lpszUserID, MAX_SIZE_USER_ID);
        memcpy(m_szUserPW, lpszUserPW, MAX_SIZE_USER_PW);
    }

    int ExecuteQuery(CNtlDatabaseConnection * pConnection)
    {
        FIND_SQLUNIT( SP_AuthLogin, pConnection, pSqlUnit2 );
        if( NULL == pSqlUnit2 )
        {
            return NTL_FAIL;
        }

        strncpy_s( pSqlUnit2->m_szUserID, m_szUserID, MAX_SIZE_USER_ID );
        strncpy_s( pSqlUnit2->m_szUserPW, m_szUserPW, MAX_SIZE_USER_ID );

        pSqlUnit2->Exec();
        printf("ExecuteQuery Done: result: %i ACC ID: %i \n", pSqlUnit2->m_nResultCode, pSqlUnit2->m_dwAccountID );

        return NTL_SUCCESS;
    }

public:
    char                m_szUserID[MAX_SIZE_USER_ID + 1];
    char                m_szUserPW[MAX_SIZE_USER_PW + 1];
};
```

This is needed for the query

```
    BEGIN_DECLARE_SQLUNIT( SP_AuthLogin, "{ ? = call AuthLogin(?,?,?) }" )
    BEGIN_VARIABLE()
        char    m_szUserID[MAX_SIZE_USER_ID + 1];
        char    m_szUserPW[MAX_SIZE_USER_PW + 1];
        int     m_dwAccountID;
        int     m_nResultCode;
    END_VARIABLE()
    BEGIN_PARAM(3)  
        PARAM_ENTRY(SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, m_nResultCode)    
        PARAM_ENTRY_STR(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, m_szUserID)
        PARAM_ENTRY_STR(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, m_szUserPW)
        PARAM_ENTRY(SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, m_dwAccountID)
    END_PARAM()
END_DECLARE_SQLUNIT()
```

Now I can get the result but the result only works inside *int ExecuteQuery*
The query results are:

```
pSqlUnit2->m_nResultCode
pSqlUnit2->m_dwAccountID
```

how can I get those 2 results in the first cpp file where I made the query?

edit: the first cpp file:

```
void CClientSession::SendCharLogInReq(CNtlPacket * pPacket) 
{
    sUA_LOGIN_REQ * req = (sUA_LOGIN_REQ *)pPacket->GetPacketData();


    HDATABASE hDB = INVALID_HDATABASE;
    CNtlDatabaseManager databaseManager;

    databaseManager.Query( hDB, new CQuery_AuthServer(req->awchUserId, req->awchPasswd) );
    //WANT RESULT HERE
}
```

I dont really know what to do.. Im really newbie

here is the complete source `https://www.sendspace.com/file/oc5v34`
at PacketAuthServer.cpp I run the query
at AuthQueryServer.h I execute the query

Comment: Have you tried passing data by parameters or as return values.  BTW, use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.  See also `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: But if I do query with many results, then it wouldn't be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard the previous answer. The problem with the previous answer is that it was expecting `databaseManager.Query` to be syncrhonous, and to execute `CQuery_AuthServer::ExecuteQuery` **before** it returns to the caller. In fact it doesn't - it just adds the query to the queue, and your database management framework doesn't give you the ability to wait for completion of that query. 
You should read the NtlDatabase manual to know how to make synchronous database calls